GAS generated embedded charts randomly do not set the right axis text color


function testLineChart() {

  /**  Define current spreadsheet  and name of sheet to contain chart */
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  /** Build the vaxes parameters */
  var vAxesOption = {};
  vAxesOption = {
    0:
    {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 12
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 8000
      },
      baselineColor: 'xffffff'
    },
    1:
    {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 12
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 20000
      },
      baselineColor: 'xffffff'
    }
  }

  /** --------------------------------------------------------------
   * Select the input data to build the chart
   * --------------------------------------------------------------*/

  var chtRange = sh.getRange(1, 1, 5, 11);
  var lineChartBuilder = sh.newChart().asLineChart();
  var chart = lineChartBuilder
    .addRange(chtRange)
    .setPosition(1, 14, 0, 0)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setOption('series', { 3: { textStyle: { color: "#ff00ff", fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 12, visibleInLegend: true }, lineWidth: 4, targetAxisIndex: 1 } })
    .setTitle('Title')
    .setOption('titleTextStyle', { color: '#ffff00', fontName: 'Arial', bold: false, fontSize: 16 })
    .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
    .setNumHeaders(1)    /** First row contains headers */
    .setOption('chartArea', { backgroundColor: "black" })
    .setOption('legend', { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: "white", fontSize: 12 } })
    .setOption('XAxis', { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: "white", fontSize: 12 } })
    .setOption('hAxis', { format: "#", textStyle: { color: "white", fontSize: 12 }, gridlines: { count: 0 }, minorGridlines: { count: 0 }, majorGridlines: { count: 0 } })
    .setBackgroundColor("black")
    .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
    .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true) /** Get the the labels from the first column */
    .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH)
    .setOption('vAxes', vAxesOption)
    .setOption('width', 700)
    .setOption('height', 400)
    .build();

  sh.insertChart(chart);

};



Embedded charts randomly and inconsistently do not set the text color for the right axis.

The expected result is shown in the image. The right axis color is not consistently set (i.e. when I select its properties the text color is still set to auto. I can manually set it to a specific color.
function lineChart(rowa, cola, rowl, coll, rowo, chtTitle, sheetName, position, suffix, second, groups, min0, max0, min1, max1) {
  /**
   *  @param: rowa is the anchor row for the input range
   *  @param: cola is the anchor column for the input range
   *  @param: rowl is the length of the input range in rows
   *  @param: coll is the length of the input range in columns
   *  @param: chtTitle is the title to be inserted in the chart
   *  @param: sheetName is the name of the target sheet for output
   *  @param: position Selects whether the chart is placed on the first, 
   *          second or third column (column defined in script properties)
   *  @param: suffix true/false indicates if last row should be highlighted  
   *  @param: second true/false specifies if the last series should be mapped 
   *          to the second axis and highlighted 
   *  @param: groups - defined which colour pallete to select
   * */

  /**  Define current spreadsheet  and name of sheet to contain chart */
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  /** Get default chart attributes from script properties */
  const ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var chartHeight = Number(ps.getProperty('chartHeight'));
  var chartWidth = Number(ps.getProperty('chartWidth'));
  var column1Chart = Number(ps.getProperty('column1Chart'));
  var column2Chart = Number(ps.getProperty('column2Chart'));
  var column3Chart = Number(ps.getProperty('column3Chart'));

  /** If suffix or second specified, add a row */
  if (suffix || second) {
    rowl = rowl + 1;
  }

  if (min0 == undefined) { min0 = '' };
  if (max0 == undefined) { max0 = '' };
  if (min1 == undefined) { min1 = '' };
  if (max1 == undefined) { max1 = '' };

  /** Set the chart position */
  switch (position) {
    case null:
      var outputColumn = column1Chart;
      break;
    case 1:
      var outputColumn = column1Chart;
      break;
    case 2:
      var outputColumn = column2Chart;
      break;
    case 3:
      var outputColumn = column3Chart;
      break;
    default:
      var outputColumn = column1Chart;
      break;
  }

  Logger.log('Line chart is in column ' + columnToLetter(outputColumn));

  /** Check if the anchor cell contains the chart ID of a previous chart 
  *  If so, first delete the chart using that id, otherwise simply create the chart */
  var chtSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng = chtSheet.getRange(rowo, outputColumn);
  var oldID = rng.getValue();
  if (oldID !== '' && oldID !== null) {
    var chartFound = deleteChartById(oldID, sheetName, rowo, outputColumn);
  }

  if (chartFound == false) {
    Logger.log('Chart with id of ' + oldID + ' not found \nLeaving old chart and skipping creation of new chart')
    Browser.msgBox('Chart with id of ' + oldID + ' not found \nLeaving old chart and skipping creation of new chart');
    return;
  }

  /** Setup default colours for series */
  /** Get corporate colours is a group; otherwise get colours
   * with the first 5 colours matching state colours */
  var seriesColoursArray = [];
  if (groups) { var seriesColoursArray = getSelectedGroupColours(); }
  else { var seriesColoursArray = getSeriesColours(); }

  /** Conditionally capture the colours for the left axis */
  var seriesColours = [];

  /** Determine how many series are for left axis */
  /** Subtract one for the header, one more if suffix or second specified */
  if (second !== true && suffix !== true) { var numPrimary = rowl - 1; }
  else { numPrimary = rowl - 2 }

  for (var r = 0; r < numPrimary; r++) {
    if (groups) { var colour = seriesColoursArray[r]; }
    else { var colour = seriesColoursArray[r][0]; }
    seriesColours.push(colour);
  }

  /** Add another colour if there is a suffix or right axis 
   *  and set the seriesWidth for the suffix or secondary series */
  if (suffix || second) {
    seriesColours.push('#ff00ff');
    var seriesWidth = 4;
  }
  else {
    var seriesWidth = 2;
  }

  /** Set the chart element colour defaults */
  var chartElementColours = [];
  var chartElementColours = getChartColours();
  var chartAreaColour = chartElementColours[0][1];
  var chartPlotColour = chartElementColours[0][1];
  var chartTextColour = chartElementColours[2][1];
  var chartGridColour = chartElementColours[4][1];

  /** Set variable for axis for last series  */
  if (second) { var axisNum = 1 } else { var axisNum = 0 };

  /** Set series number variable for last series */
  var seriesNum = seriesColours.length - 1;

  /** Set series number variable for last series */
  if (seriesColours.length > 1) {
    var seriesNum = seriesColours.length - 1;
  }
  else {
    seriesNum = 0;
  }


  /** Build series option for last series */
  var seriesOption = {};
  seriesOption[seriesNum] = {
    textStyle: {
      color: chartTextColour,
      fontName: 'Arial',
      fontSize: 12,
      visibleInLegend: true
    },
    lineWidth: seriesWidth,
    targetAxisIndex: axisNum
  }

  /** Build the left vaxis parameters */
  var vAxesOption = {};
  vAxesOption = {
    0:
    {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 12
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: min0,
        max: max0
      },
      baselineColor: 'xffffff'
    },
    1:
    {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 12
      },
      viewWindow: {
        min: min1,
        max: max1
      },
      baselineColor: 'xffffff'
    }
  }

  // Logger.log('Axes options = ' + JSON.stringify(vAxesOption, null, 2))

  /** --------------------------------------------------------------
   * Select the input data to build the chart
   * --------------------------------------------------------------*/

  var chtRange = sh.getRange(rowa, cola, rowl, coll);
  var lineChartBuilder = sh.newChart().asLineChart();
  var chart = lineChartBuilder
    .addRange(chtRange)
    .setPosition(rowo, outputColumn, 0, 0)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setTitle(chtTitle)
    .setColors(seriesColours)
    .setOption('titleTextStyle', { color: '#ffff00', fontName: 'Arial', bold: false, fontSize: 16 })
    .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
    .setNumHeaders(1)    /** First row contains headers */
    .setOption('chartArea', { backgroundColor: chartPlotColour })
    .setOption('legend', { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: chartTextColour, fontSize: 12 } })
    .setOption('XAxis', { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: chartTextColour, fontSize: 12 } })
    .setOption('hAxis', { format: "#", textStyle: { color: chartTextColour, fontSize: 12 }, gridlines: { count: 0 }, minorGridlines: { count: 0 }, majorGridlines: { count: 0 } })
    .setBackgroundColor(chartAreaColour)
    .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
    .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true) /** Get the the labels from the first column */
    .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH)
    .setOption('series', seriesOption)
    .setOption('vAxes', vAxesOption)
    .setOption('width', chartWidth)
    .setOption('height', chartHeight)
    .build();

  sh.insertChart(chart);
  var newID = chart.getChartId();

  /** Store the chart ID in case we want to subsequently delete or modify it  */
  var rng = chtSheet.getRange(rowo, outputColumn);
  rng.setValue(newID);
};

The vAxesOption defines the color as white.
Any help to either resolve the issue of do better debugging would be greatly appreciated. (This has been a recurring issue for at least 2-3 years so is unlikely to be a recent code change).




2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023




Entity1
2,558
2,651
2,712
2,703
2,658
2,571
2,596
2,819
2,886
3,043


Entity2
4,420
4,472
4,407
4,673
5,278
5,658
5,954
6,137
6,163
6,324


Entity3
2,480
2,218
2,164
2,294
2,580
2,886
3,256
4,123
5,303
5,992


Totals
9k
9k
9k
10k
11k
11k
12k
13k
14k
15k




Please "minify" your code to the actual [mre].

Minimised code aded as a snippet.

Thank you! Could you please also add a markdown table with your sample data? You can use this tool to create it easily.

Thanks for pointing me to that tool. I have been able to generate a markdown table but I am struggling to see how to either add it to the question or (ideally) replace the long code section in the body without totally replacing the body

Your issue is indeed reproducible. I do not have a solution for you, but here's the information I've gathered so far:

the problem does indeed lie in the text colour of the right axis - and only the right axis, that stays black;
the problem isn't solved by adding  .setYAxisTextStyle(Charts.newTextStyle().setColor('white')), neither by re-setting .setOption('vAxes', {1: {textStyle: {color: 'white'}}}) a second time;
the problem isn't solved by "stripping down" the options to just setting the text colour of the axis;
the problem is indeed inconsistent and occurs with a frequency which belongs to the 95% Confidence Interval [0.48, 0.64];
when a loop is used to generate N graphs in a row, either all of them will have the correct output, or all of them will present the bug;
the above point applies even when setting Utilities.sleep() between each iteration;
the problem can be replicated by setting triggers every minute to the testLineChart function;
there's a second inconsistency concerning the viewWindow (range) of - once again - the right axis's values: sometimes the specified settings are applied, other times it defaults to the left axis' viewWindow;
for which types of graphs the issue appears still needs to be tested.

There are a lot of bugs concerning vAxis and vAxes, including the impossibility of reading their properties' values through EmbeddedChart.getOptions().get('vAxes.1.textStyle.color') (or any other property), which just returns null1.
The closest exiting bugs on Google Issue Tracker that I found are this one and this one - see also their comments. You can star them to make Google prioritise them; or you can decide to create a new one. In the latter case, I would suggest adding the link here.

1 See this answer.

This isn't really an answer, but it's a bit too long for comments and may be clearer this way.

Thanks for verifying my sanity. This issue has been around for at least 4 years and my spreadsheet has approximately 450 charts. It is very time intensive to manually update >200 charts after code updates or changing reporting years.

That's what I would call a pain in the arsenal. I have no idea how you could automate that, since the bug I talk about (property returning null) makes it impossible to check the validity of a generated chart. Maybe there's some other way to do that that I haven't thought of.

Just a little more information and a hypothesis...
The null response when querying the chart does preclude remediation.
However, I set up a test where I created 6 charts in 1 execution of the function. Each execution result in every chart setting the text colour or every chart having the default. Therefore my hypothesis is that it depends on which server the function is dispatched on as to the result and there may be a server (or several) with backlevel code.

I have implemented a very crude circumvention.
In the chart generation code, if there is to be a right axis, I set the value of 'right axis' in the cell of the second row behind the chart.
Since I know that all charts will be either correct of incorrect for a single execution of a function, I am coding a side bar to prompt for the sheet to process and the loop through every chart on the sheet. If it has 'right axis' in that cell I modify with the same vaxes parameters.
Now every matching chart will either default or have white. I run the function iteratively until it works.
